# Error can't get value other from input type hidden

Tags: jquery

index.php i am using:

```
<script src="srcipt.js"></script>
    <div id="demo">
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="id" value='1' />test1</h3>
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="id" value='2' />test2</h3>
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="id" value='3' />test3</h3>
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="id" value='4' />test4</h3>
        <h3><input type="hidden" name="id" value='5' />test5</h3>
    </div>
```

in script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

When I click on "test1" result 1
, click on "test2" result 1
...
, click on "test5" result 1

> How to get value when click on "test2" is result 2, how to fix it ?

Comment: Haven't you mispelled "script.js" up top? <script src="srcipt.js"></script>

Comment: He has, but it's clearly just an editing error in his question, since the JS is actually running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).children('input').eq(0).val();
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

That should work!

`$(this)` refers to your h3 element. Why would you go to the parent first to search for an input? You can just get the first input element of the selected h3 element!

Also, please note that give multiple `input` elements the same `name` is a bad practise in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the call to `parent()` in you code. Try this:

```
var id = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
```

Given the structure of your HTML, you could improve the performance of this with just:

```
var id = $(this).find('input').val();
```

I have to say though, the HTML seems rather odd, why are you putting `input` elements in to a `H3`? Why are you repeating an input with the same `name` attribute in each `H3`?

I think what you're doing here could be better achieved by using `data()`. [Further information here](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.parent()` is unnecessary because `$(this)` refers the the `h3`. Use the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val()
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehjmv/).

**Additional Information:**

There are many ways to skin this cat. For example, if the hidden element will always be the first element inside the `h3`, you could grab the first child like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).children().eq(0).val()
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `parent()`, just use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

See this in [live](http://jsfiddle.net/4gc6N/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `parent()` before `find()`, you're matching the hidden inputs in *all* the `<h3>` elements inside `#demo`. Since you only want to match the hidden input below the clicked `<h3>` element, you have to remove the call to `parent()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo h3").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).find("input:hidden[name=id]").val();
       alert(id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#demo h3').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).children("input[type='hidden']").val();
       alert(id);
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fg8KJ/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you could do this. The basic problem is that your code only finds the value of the first match for the selector.

```
var id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
```

I think that taking out the .parent() will help.  $(this) refers to the H3 being clicked, so you shouldn't need to go up to the parent to find the contained INPUT tag.

```
var id = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
```

You could also give each input an ID attribute and search by that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="input1" />
```

And then search by input

```
var id = $(this).parent().find('input#input1').val();
```

I'm suggesting this as a good practice in case you'd need to find the input values from other areas on your page.